# Electronjs ipcRenderer.on not working properly

Tags: electron, ipc, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

I am trying to send data from the main process to the renderer and the ipcRenderer.on function is being executed but the data is undefined...

This is the code to send the data:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
        let name = "test";
        mainWindow.webContents.send("updateSave", name);
})
```

And this to receive it:

```
ipcRenderer.on("updateSave", (e, data) => {
    console.log("data: " + data);
})
```

The console.log is beeing fired but it just says: data: undefined

And this is the preload file:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", {
    send: (channel, ...args) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args),
    on: (channel, func) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))    
});
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `preload.js`, you're defining `ipcRenderer.on()` as follows:

```js
on: (channel, func) => {
    ipcRenderer.on(
        channel,
        (event, ...args) => {
            func(...args)
        }
    )
}
```

Thus, `event` will never get passed to `func()` and is thus swallowed. Now, there are two possible solutions (personally, I'd go with (1) because it's easiest to implement and will make for cleaner code on both parts. However, please see the remark below):

**(1) You want to keep the signature in your renderer**
I.e., you want to still write `ipcRenderer.on("channel", (event, data) => {});`. Then you will have to change your preload code. I suggest to simply pass `func` to ipcRenderer like so:

```js
on: (channel, func) => ipcRenderer.on (channel, func)
```

Then, any `func` parameter must have the signature `(event, ...data) => {}`.

**(2) You want to keep the signature in your preload**
I.e., you want to keep the code of your preload `contextBridge` definition. Then, any instance of `ipcRenderer.on()` in your renderer code will need to change to fit the signature `(...data) => {}` since there's no `event` parameter passed to the function.

---

As a side note, it is considered a best practice if you *don't* expose Electron API function (such as `ipcRenderer.on()`, `ipcRenderer.send()` etc) to the renderer when proxying using a preload script, but instead provide discrete functions for your renderer code to choose from, as shown in [Electron's official IPC tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. I've been trying to solve this for days now...